# [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module

Tags: next.js, antd

[ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules@antv\g-base\node_modules\d3-interpolate\src\index.js from F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules@antv\g-base\lib\animate\timeline.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules@antv\g-base\lib\animate\timeline.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
at Object. (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules@antv\g-base\lib\animate\timeline.js:5:24)
at Object. (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules@antv\g-base\lib\abstract\canvas.js:7:18)
at Object. (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules@antv\g-base\lib\index.js:17:16)
at Object. (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules@antv\g2\lib\dependents.js:6:16)
at Object. (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules@antv\g2\lib\util\scale.js:7:20)
at Object. (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules@antv\g2\lib\util\axis.js:6:15)
at Object. (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules@antv\g2\lib\facet\facet.js:7:14)
at Object. (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules@antv\g2\lib\facet\index.js:5:15)
at Object. (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules@antv\g2\lib\chart\view.js:8:15)
at Object. (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules@antv\g2\lib\chart\chart.js:8:38)
at Object. (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules@antv\g2\lib\chart\index.js:7:15)
at Object. (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules@antv\g2\lib\core.js:8:15)
at Object. (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules@antv\g2\lib\index.js:6:14)
at Object. (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules@antv\g2plot\lib\index.js:8:31)
at Object. (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules@ant-design\plots\lib\components\area\index.js:41:16)
at Object. (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules@ant-design\plots\lib\index.js:21:30)
at Object.2890 (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe.next\server\pages\cil\view.js:1617:18)
at **webpack_require** (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
at Object.2073 (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe.next\server\pages\cil\view.js:60:14)
at **webpack_require** (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
at **webpack_exec** (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe.next\server\pages\cil\view.js:1732:39)
at F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe.next\server\pages\cil\view.js:1733:141
at Function.**webpack_require**.X (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:195:21)
at F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe.next\server\pages\cil\view.js:1733:47
at Object. (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe.next\server\pages\cil\view.js:1736:3)
at Object.requirePage (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules\next\dist\server\require.js:58:12)
at F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-components.js:61:73
at async Object.loadComponents (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-components.js:61:26)
at async F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:798:32
at async Span.traceAsyncFn (F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20) {
code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}

> Build error occurred
> Error: Failed to collect page data for /cil/view
> at F:\Apsis project\batb-lim-fe\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:916:15
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
> type: 'Error'
> }
> error Command failed with exit code 1.
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

want to build this in next js but facing this issue. how can i solvve this problem?